# python missing one required positional argument?

Tags: function, printing, output, jupyter

I am defining a function and trying to print the result of this function however i am getting the error message:

> temp_of_seawater() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'

Relevant code:

```
def temp_of_seawater(l, d):                                                                               
    temp_of_seawater = ((gradient * d) + temp_surfacelevel_1)
    return temp_of_seawater(d)
 print("The temperature at your given latitude and depth is:", 
 temp_of_seawater(d) , "\u00b0""C")
```

Comment: temp_of_seawater(l, d) requires two parameters viz 'l' and 'd' and you are passing only 1 value. Hence the value you are passing is assigned to 'l' and there is no value for 'd', so you get the error that missing 1 required positional argument: '\d'

Comment: How do I change it so that it passes two values ?

Comment: you pass two values like temp_of_seawater(x, d), where x is some variable. or change the definition of temp_of_seawater(l, d) to temp_of_seawater(d)